# Geoserver WMS get request by id

Tags: geoserver, wms, wfs

I have a layer on geoserver and I want to get JSON result of a single river. For example get river id=2541.

I see examples that using BBOX. But I do not use BBOX on my wms query.

```
http://geoserveraddres:8080/geoserver/MFG/wms?REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&SERVICE=WMS&INFO_FORMAT=application/json&QUERY_LAYERS=MFG%3Ariver
```

How can I get by id?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WMS isn't for this. WMS returns a map image, and won't provide you with the JSON you desire.

What you want is **WFS (Web Feature Service)** which allows you to request and receive the raw data hosted by the service, including in JSON format.

From this document - http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wfs/reference.html - you'd want something like:

`http://example.com/geoserver/wfs?
  service=wfs&
  version=2.0.0&
  request=GetFeature&
  typeNames=namespace:featuretype&
  featureID=feature`

Although the "featureID" is the GeoServer specific ID I believe and may not be the same as your river_id.

You'd also want to add `&outputFormat=application/json` to get JSON - http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wfs/outputformats.html

If you want a more complicated search (i.e., one for a specific river_id), I believe you're going to need to use an XML POST request rather than a URL GET request, or maybe CQL - http://docs.geoserver.org/2.1.3/user/services/wfs/vendor.html.

There are also some examples within GeoServer itself - `Demo's -> Demo requests -> WFS*`